# ns2 projects in wireless networks

Tags: wireless, ns2

how to construct tree in ns2 and how to write routing protocol in ns2?
clustered nodes to be arranged in tree structure and code for deflection routing in ns2.
I also need to know how to increase the energy of a node and how to make a node inactive.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so that your future questions better fit Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

For simulating the energy of nodes the example in `tcl/ex/wireless-newnode-energy.tcl`

Also, to see the available command for changing the energy of a node during simulation, see see source files in `mac/wireless-phy.cc`, method `int WirelessPhy::command(int argc, const char*const* argv)`

To implement your own routing protocol in ns2, read [this article](http://imtl.skku.ac.kr/~hjlim99/ns2/%5b%BB%F5%B7%CE%BF%EE%20%B6%F3%BF%EC%C6%C3%20%C7%C1%B7%CE%C5%E4%C4%DD%20%B1%B8%C7%F6%5d/Implementing%20a%20New%20Manet%20Unicast%20Routing%20Protocol%20in%20ns2.pdf)

I did not fully understand the part about the tree structure and the deflection.